# How to set order to Expandablelistview?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'm new to Android, developing an Event app.The app has a child event so I have used expandable listview but its order is different from Arraylist object order. Already I used sort function & its working but I need to ordering my order.

How to fix this?

DataPump.java

```
public class ExpandableListDataPump {
    public static HashMap<String, List<String>> getData(ArrayList<Guide> guides) {
        HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        List<String> parent = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < guides.size(); i++) {
            parent=new ArrayList<>();
            Guide guide=guides.get(i);
//            Log.e("size***",guide.getName()+"-"+ String.valueOf(guide.getItem_list().size()));

            if (guide.getItem_list().isEmpty()){

            }else{
                for (int j=0;j<guide.getItem_list().size();j++){
                    parent.add(guide.getItem_list().get(j).getName());
//                    Log.e("add****", String.valueOf(guides.get(i).getItem_list().get(j).getName()));

                }

            }
            expandableListDetail.put(guide.getName(), parent);

        }
```

in Activity  class,

```
expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.exLv_events);
        expandableListDetail = ExpandableListDataPump.getData(guideArrayList);
        expandableListTitle = new ArrayList<String>(expandableListDetail.keySet());
//        Collections.sort(expandableListTitle);

        expandableListAdapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(this, expandableListTitle, expandableListDetail);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
```

Comment: Share your code and error log?

Comment: no error log R2R

Comment: _I need to ordering my order?_ You need to sort your children items in a list item?

Comment: i need to order the parent item,finally i solved

Answer (score 0):

I changed HashMap to LinkedHashMap,then problem solved,

code snipts,
datapump.java

```
public class ExpandableListDataPump {
    public static LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> getData(ArrayList<Guide> guides) {
        LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        List<String> parent = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < guides.size(); i++) {
            parent=new ArrayList<>();
            Guide guide=guides.get(i);
            Log.e("dpump***",guide.getName());

            if (guide.getItem_list().isEmpty()){

            }else{
                for (int j=0;j<guide.getItem_list().size();j++){
                    parent.add(guide.getItem_list().get(j).getName());
//                    Log.e("add****", String.valueOf(guides.get(i).getItem_list().get(j).getName()));

                }

            }
//            expandableListDetail.put(guide.getName(), parent);
            expandableListDetail.put(guide.getName(), parent);
            Log.e("size###", String.valueOf(expandableListDetail.size()));

        }

        return expandableListDetail;
    }
}
```

and activity

LinkedHashMap> expandableListDetail;

and when loading,

```
 expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.exLv_events);
        expandableListDetail = ExpandableListDataPump.getData(guideArrayList);
        expandableListTitle = new ArrayList<String>(expandableListDetail.keySet());
        expandableListAdapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(this, expandableListTitle, expandableListDetail);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
```